# Codeception db credentials on bootstrap file

Tags: codeception

i need a dynamic option here. But everytime need to enable the db module with credentials in the yml file. How can i use there constants or move it to the _bootstrap.php?

See you and thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was to use a sqlite db in the yml file and use a helper to reconfigure the db setting